# Visual Studio 2013 Connection Error with Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to update my C# Visual Studio SQL Server database.  It is stored locally as an .mdf file.  However, when I go into view the table data in the VS GUI, and I try to add a new record or modify a record I get the error:

> Executed SQL Statement: Select TOP 1000 ...column names here... FROM
>   ..Table Here... 
>   Error Source: System.Dara
>   Error Message: Invalid
>   Operation.  Connection is closed.

I know its obvious its a connection problem, but I have no idea where VS runs its SQL code from, or any idea how the connection got closed.  I cannot shut down Visual Studio because the same error message appears and won't let me even close the view data tab.

Comment: Show us the code where you are trying to execute your SQL/EF statements.

Comment: `VS > View > ServerExplorer`

Comment: I said it was inside the Visual Studio 2013 View Data when you go to a table, right-click it and click "view data", so its not my code.  But the connection is fine when I test it under "Modify Connection".

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause or Break</kbd>  and then click Refresh or press(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) in your table view

It's worked for me